# Why isn't this circuit working in Falstad as expected?

Tags: mosfet, falstad

While trying to simulate a simple circuit using a N-Channel MOSFET, I encountered a problem. while supplying 3.3V to the GATE pin, I would expect a way higher current to flow, more like 7A. But according to the Falstad simulator, only 32.4mA would flow. The threshold voltage is 1.5V. Why does only so little current flow? [image]

Comment: what is the meaning of the red dot? ... what is the meaning of the white line section?

Comment: Threshold voltage is specified at microamps Ids, the very first beginnings of an inversion channel. "Real" current doesn't begin to flow until Vgs is significantly higher. What is the part number of the transistor you are using?

Comment: Could you add a URL for your Flastad circuit to your question. That way others can play with it, check the parameters of the MOSFET etc.

Comment: This is the Link for the simulation: https://shorturl.at/qEJP6 The used MOSFET is just the standard N-Channel MOSFET from the Flastad component list. The red dot just means that there is a bad connection there, but even after correcting that error, I still get only a small current flow, while the white line is a simple switch.

Comment: Increase the "beta" value https://www.falstad.com/circuit/mosfet-beta.html

Comment: 3.3V is a low gate voltage. Try > 7V.

Comment: @Fazeli24 please add the falstad link into your question ... a comment os not the place for such infornation ... this site is not a forum ... comments are not part of the question

Comment: And the full original url will automatically self-truncate. Please don't drop url-shortener links that could go anywhere.

Comment: Okay, I will keep that in mind when posting links. But since the URL was very long, I couldn't post the comment, because of to many characters.

Comment: @Fazeli24 you were not asked to post the link in a comment. You were asked by several people to add it into your question. Please do so.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy okay, but my question was already answered and the problem is solved. I can still add it, but I don't think it is necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the "Beta" to 20.

[Here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/mosfet-beta.html) is an explanation of how to get numbers that sort-of fit a real MOSFET from looking at the datasheet.

If you want more accurate results something like LTspice might be better.

Comment: Okay, so using the calculator and the datasheet of my MOSFET, I get a beta value of 3.921568627450981, which is way closer to what I expected. (In my case this will be around 7A). But my datasheet says that the threshold voltage is anywhere from 1 - 2.5V, which is a huge difference for my application. Is there a way to drive my MOSFET with the full battery voltage(8.4V) instead of my Microcontroller voltage(3.3V)?

Comment: Yes, add a transistor  or three, or a MOSFET driver chip. The details depend on how fast you need to switch the MOSFET etc. You could also use a more appropriate MOSFET. This is a new question.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that. Thank you for your answer, you solved my problem.